# Mui(mui.com) Data Grid - How add a Summary row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-datatable

I am using Data Table from MUI, docs below.

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#data-table
https://mui.com/

I am trying to add a summary row in my table, but I dont understand how.

Any Idea is apreciated.

My actual code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { DataGrid, GridRowsProp, GridColDef } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

import './Invoice.scss';

const Invoice = () => {

  const rows = [
    { id: 1, col1: '1', col2: '', col3: 'Power Sweeping1', col4: '', col5: '1', col6: '$1.350,00', col7: '$1.350,00' },
    { id: 1, col1: '1', col2: '', col3: 'Power Sweeping2', col4: '', col5: '1', col6: '$1.350,00', col7: '$1.350,00' },
    { id: 1, col1: '1', col2: '', col3: 'Power Sweeping3', col4: '', col5: '1', col6: '$1.350,00', col7: '$1.350,00' },
  ];

  const columns = [
    { field: 'col1', headerName: '#', width: 10 },
    { field: 'col2', headerName: 'Date', width: 150 },
    { field: 'col3', headerName: 'Product or service', width: 250 },
    { field: 'col4', headerName: 'SKU', width: 150 },
    { field: 'col5', headerName: 'Qty', width: 150 },
    { field: 'col6', headerName: 'Rate', width: 150 },
    { field: 'col7', headerName: 'Amount', width: 150 },
  ];

  return  (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Invoice</h1>
      <div id='table' className='row'>
        <div style={{ height: 300, width: '100%' }}>
          <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} 
            hideFooterPagination="true"
            hideFooterSelectedRowCount="true"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
)};

export default Invoice;
```

Expectation:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a footer using the slots and slotProps props.

```
slots={{
    footer: CustomFooterStatusComponent,
}}
slotProps={{
     footer: { sum },
}}
```

Have a look at [this example](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/components/#footer) on DataGrid component.

First you need to create a custom component, then you have to pass it through the "slots" prop.

Finally, send the data you need through the "slotProps" prop (The Sum for example)

```
export function CustomFooterStatusComponent(props) {

return (
    <Box sx={{ p: 1, display: "flex", justifyContent: "end" }}>
      SUM {props.sum}
    </Box>
  );
```

}

**JS Reduce example**

```
const dataToSum = [10, 20, 30, 40];
const sum = dataToSum.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you give any direction to sumarize the value? I saw the example of Docs but they are not summarizing.

Comment: You can use a reduce function to iterate and sum over your rows array : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-numbers-in-javascript-arrays/

Comment: I get the example, but it is complex to me, could you please, help using the code example? export function CustomFooterStatusComponent(props) {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ p: 1, display: 'flex' }}>
      <FiberManualRecordIcon
        fontSize="small"
        sx={{
          mr: 1,
          color: props.status === 'connected' ? '#4caf50' : '#d9182e',
        }}
      />
      Status {props.status}
    </Box>
  );
}

Comment: Just completed the answer above